# User-proofing tips for Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: database, forms, ms-access-2010

I have built a basic database using Microsoft Access 2010 as a tool meant to improve the logging of information (prior, the information was manually collected into very messy Excel spreadsheets). Now, there is a simple form that auto-populates the relational tables cleanly and in a standardized manner.

Long story short - if I want to hand this database back to the team who were originally logging the information, are there simple yet effective gold standards for "user-proofing" the database beyond hiding critical sub forms, disabling non-form views, and removing toolbars from view? I have also read up on [splitting the database](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/databasesplitter/), which could be a path forward as well to secure the back end of the database. The team isn't very fluent with Excel beyond basic functions, and I expect to train them up on Access usage at least to a basic capacity so they can maintain the database themselves long-term.

The specific goal is to protect the input enough so they are not likely to edit the actual tables and break the relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ideally you keep you backend/front-end separate. so splitting it would be the way to go. if you create a decent form in your front-end , then users don't need to train , or understand Access, they would simply interact with your form. if that is designed well, then it would look like a windows application, and much of your users couldn't tell that they are actually in Access.

There are many pieces to this that i can't possibly comment here, and you certainly are not limited to using Access as a front-end, but i gather that is not an option for you right now.